# Next.js & Passport.js/Express: How to debug "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" response

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, next.js, semantic-ui-react, passport-local

I have a login component/form which checks for validation errors on the client and essentially the process follows after a submit with some server (checking for a user, seeing if a user verified) against the database.

The strange thing which is happening, I am getting:

From the network tab:

```
 http://localhost:8016/users/login 401 (Unauthorized)
```

& From the client:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What is weird about the `Uncaught TypeError`, it originates:

Inside some logic which should only be firing from a response from the server if you **have** registered and exist in the database but **have not** verified.
Right now I cleared the database of users and its jumping to that?

Despite only having these responses on this route:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  var user = req.user;

  if (user === undefined) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      msg: [
        `We were unable to find this user.`,
        `This email and/or password combo may be incorrect.
          Please confirm with the "Forgot password" link above or the "Register" link below!`
      ]
    });
  }

  if (user && user.isVerified === false) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      msg: [
        'Your username has not been verified!',
        'Check your email for a confirmation link.'
      ]
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(200).send({
      msg: [`Your have successfully logged in;`, `Welcome to Hillfinders!`]
    });
  }
});
```

What's more is when I look in the network tab to see what the response is to get a more refined take I just get:

[image]

My responses follow a format where I send the status code for my client and a message which I use for the UI for the client as well:

Excerpt from login:

if (user && user.isVerified === false) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      msg: [
        'Your username has not been verified!',
        'Check your email for a confirmation link.'
      ]
    });
  } else {

This is my form component:

I omitted the other pieces of the form as they don't matter to the question:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  Loader,
  Input,
  Dimmer,
  Transition,
  Button,
  Form,
  Grid,
  Header,
  Message,
  Segment
} from 'semantic-ui-react';

import axios from 'axios';

import {
  logInUser,
  userHasBeenVerified,
  userHasNotBeenVerified,
  resetUserAcoountVerified
} from '../../store/reducers/users/index';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { validateInputs } from '../../utils/index';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Container } from 'next/app';

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const MyMap = dynamic(() => import('../Map/MyMap.jsx'), {
  ssr: false
});

function FormComponent({
  formType,
  match,
  history,
  logInUser,
  accountNotVerified,
  userHasBeenVerified,
  userHasNotBeenVerified,
  resetUserAcoountVerified
}) {
  var Forms = {
    Hillfinders: [isHillfindersForm],
    Confirmation: [isConfirmationForm],
    ForgotPassword: [isForgotPasswordForm, forgotPasswordSubmit],
    Login: [isLoginForm, loginSubmit],
    Registration: [isRegisterForm, registerSubmit],
    UpdatePassword: [isUpdatePasswordForm, updatePasswordSubmit]
  };

  var [duration, setDuration] = useState(500);
  var [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  var [usernameFeedback, setUsernameFeedback] = useState('');
  var [usernameError, setUsernameError] = useState(false);
  var [userNameDup, setUserNameDup] = useState(false);
  var [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  var [passwordFeedback, setPasswordFeedback] = useState('');
  var [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState(false);
  var [password_confirmation, setPasswordConfirmation] = useState('');
  var [passwordConfirmationError, setPasswordConfirmationError] = useState(false);
  var [passwordConfirmationFeedback, setPasswordConfirmationFeedback] = useState('');
  var [formSuccess, setFormSuccess] = useState(false);
  var [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);
  var [disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false);
  var [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  var [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState(['', '']);
  var [tokenExpired, setTokenExpired] = useState(false);
  var [responseCodeSuccess, setResponseCodeSuccess] = useState(false);
  var [error, setError] = useState(false);

  function isLoginForm() {
    console.log('accountNotVerified ', accountNotVerified);
    useEffect(() => {}, []);

    return (
      <div className="login-form">
        {' '}
        {}
        <style>
          {`body > div, body > div > div, body > div > div > div.login-form { height: 100%;}`}{' '}
        </style>
        <Grid textAlign="center" style={{ height: '100%' }} verticalAlign="middle">
          <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
            <Header as="h2" color="green" textAlign="center">
              Log-in to your account
            </Header>

            <Form
              size="large"
              onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e, formType)}
              error={formError}
            >
              <Segment stacked>
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon="user"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  placeholder="E-mail address, e.g. joe@schmoe.com"
                  name="username"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <Transition visible={usernameError} animation="scale" duration={duration}>
                  <Message error content={usernameFeedback} />
                </Transition>
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon="lock"
                  iconPosition="left"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                />
                <Transition visible={passwordError} animation="scale" duration={duration}>
                  <Message error content={passwordFeedback} />
                </Transition>
                <Button color="green" fluid size="large" disabled={disableButton}>
                  Log-in
                </Button>
                <br />
                <Link to="/forgot_password">Forgot password?</Link>

                <Transition
                  visible={accountNotVerified}
                  unmountOnHide={true}
                  animation="scale"
                  duration={duration}
                >
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Dimmer active inverted>
                      <Loader />
                    </Dimmer>
                  ) : (
                    <Message
                      warning
                      color="yellow"
                      centered="true"
                      header={responseMessage[0]}
                      content={responseMessage[1]}
                    />
                  )}
                </Transition>

                <Transition
                  visible={formError}
                  unmountOnHide={true}
                  animation="scale"
                  duration={duration}
                >
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Dimmer active inverted>
                      <Loader />
                    </Dimmer>
                  ) : (
                    <Message
                      error
                      centered="true"
                      header={responseMessage[0]}
                      content={responseMessage[1]}
                    />
                  )}
                </Transition>

                <Transition
                  visible={formSuccess}
                  unmountOnHide={true}
                  animation="scale"
                  duration={duration}
                >
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Dimmer active inverted>
                      <Loader />
                    </Dimmer>
                  ) : (
                    <Message
                      success
                      header={responseMessage[0]}
                      content={responseMessage[1]}
                    />
                  )}
                </Transition>
              </Segment>
            </Form>
            {formError ? (
              <Transition visible={formError} animation="scale" duration={1000}>
                {isLoading ? (
                  <Dimmer active inverted>
                    <Loader />
                  </Dimmer>
                ) : (
                  <Message>
                    <Link to="/register">Register</Link>{' '}
                  </Message>
                )}
              </Transition>
            ) : null}
          </Grid.Column>{' '}
        </Grid>{' '}
      </div>
    );
  }



  function loginSubmit() {
    axios
      .post('/users/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            logInUser();
            history.push('/profile');
          }, 5000);

          setUsername('');
          setPassword('');
          setFormError(false);
          setFormSuccess(true);
          setIsLoading(false);
          setResponseMessage(response.data.msg);
          userHasBeenVerified();
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response) {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            setUsername('');
            setPassword('');
            setFormError(false);
            setFormSuccess(false);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          }
          if (error.response.status === 404) {
            setUsername('');
            setPassword('');
            setFormError(true);
            setFormSuccess(false);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
          }
        }
      });
  }


  function handleChange(e) {
    e.persist();
    setFormError(false);
    setFormSuccess(false);
    setUsernameError(false);
    setPasswordError(false);
    setDisableButton(false);

    resetUserAcoountVerified();
    setUserNameDup(false);

    if (e.target.name === 'username') {
      setUsername(e.target.value);
    }

    if (e.target.name === 'password') {
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    }

    if (e.target.name === 'password_confirmation') {
      setPasswordConfirmation(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  function handleSubmit(event, formType) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('before validate');
    validateInputs(
      formType,
      username,
      setUsernameError,
      setUsernameFeedback,
      password,
      password_confirmation,
      setPasswordConfirmationError,
      setPasswordConfirmationFeedback,
      setPasswordError,
      setPasswordFeedback,
      setDisableButton,
      setFormSuccess,
      setFormError
    );
    console.log('after validate');

    return Forms[formType][1]();
  }
  return Forms[formType][0]();
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { users } = state;
  const { accountNotVerified, isLoggedIn } = users;

  return { accountNotVerified, isLoggedIn };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    { logInUser, userHasBeenVerified, userHasNotBeenVerified, resetUserAcoountVerified },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FormComponent);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
Ajeet below made a good point so  I am including the auth portion too from passport-local:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var UserModel = require('../models/userModel');

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    { usernameField: 'username', passwordField: 'password' },
    async (username, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username }).exec();
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid username!' });
        }
        const passwordOk = await user.comparePassword(password);

        if (!passwordOk) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Invalid password!'
          });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
    }
  )
);

// eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user._id));

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findById(id).exec(); //exec is used to get a real Promise
    return done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
});

module.exports = {
  initialize: passport.initialize(),
  session: passport.session(),
  setUser: (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    return next();
  }
};
```

I thought when you hit that route though the `passport-local` strategy fires thus helping with my routes functions...

Comment: I think you are expecting `req.user` i.e. `user` at backend but sending `username` from frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe I am thinking `passport-local` is supposed to do more, but isn't supposed to do that? Like I send my email, it authenticates it....